# DateTime formatting to remove time if not time is zero (00:00:00)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, format

I have a page to display content of different tables upon user selection.
These tables have fields `DateTime` type, but time is not always relevant, specially when time is `00:00:00`

These means that, sometimes the table to display might have a BirthDate column where time is irrelevant, others might have CreatedOn where time is necessary to be displayed in the view.

I am not able to specifically set a format for an specific column as the view can show any table, however in code behind (C#) I am able to identify if a column is DateTime type and set a format before displayng.

Using condition like:

```
DataTable dt0 = dsDataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
foreach (DataColumn column in dt0.Columns)
{
    if (column.DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
    {
            var printDateFormat = dtfi.ShortDatePattern;
            :..
            :..
    }
}
```

The result will be `dd-MM-yyyy` for all DateTime columns, and will remove the time for columns even for those columns for which time is needed to be displayed.

An ideal solution should display the data as follow:

```
in DB -> DateTime  |In Page View| in DB -> DateTime |In Page View       |
===================|============|===================|===================|
BirthDate          |            |Created On         |                   |
===================|============|===================|===================|
07/03/2014 00:00:00|07/03/2014  |05/03/2015 03:04:01|05/03/2015 03:04:01|
12/01/2014 00:00:00|12/01/2014  |03/01/2015 06:05:01|03/01/2015 06:05:01|
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You give a little code snippet that isn't valid C#. Show us the method where that code would be located.

Comment: You could check if `value.Hours == 0 && value.Minutes == 0 && value.Seconds == 0` for all values in a column to apply the ShortDatePattern.

Comment: How do *you* know that "Created On" should show the time and "BirthDate" should not?

Comment: When the data is loaded from Oracle or SQL server to a DataSet the field for Date or DataTime is the same type in a DataSet (DateTime)
So as requirement we need to strip out the time when time is zero (00:00:00) like for birthdate for example.

Comment: Where are you going to use the data containing the `DateTime`? Because datetime has no format until you use it somwhere and specify the format.

Comment: You can't apply a format to `DataTable`. You need to apply a format to `DataGrid` column after data binding.

Comment: Data is loaded from oracle or sql server to DataTable.
It will be then displayed in gridview and/or downloadable into Excel.
Problem is that DataTable only recognizes data type DateTime.
So Date or DateTime will have the same data type and because the view show different tables with multiple date columns, I can’t hardcode and say for Colum0 format will be ShortDatePattern.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, I am not applying the format to the `DataTable`, I am applying the format to the container which will display the data (Gridview or Excel) based on the data type of the `DataTable/Column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new DataTable, replacing the DateTime column to a string column, specifying the desired format.

```
// DataTable with original data
// May contain DataTime with zero time.
var dt = new DataTable();

// DataTable with Date converted to string.
var dt2 = new DataTable();

var dateIndexes = new HashSet<int>();

// Create columns in dt2, changing DateTime with zero time to string type
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    if (column.DataType == typeof(DateTime) &&
        dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => (DateTime)row[column])
            .All(dateTime => dateTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0))
    {
        // If all time is zero then create string type column.
        dt2.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
        // Remember the index of the column with zero time
        dateIndexes.Add(column.Ordinal);
    }
    else
    {
        // Create column same type.
        dt2.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
    }
}

// Copy rows
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var newRow = dt2.NewRow();
    dt2.Rows.Add(newRow);

    for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dateIndexes.Contains(i))
        {
            // Column with zero time. Convert it to string.
            newRow[i] = ((DateTime)row[i]).ToShortDateString();
        }
        else
        {
            // Copy as is.
            newRow[i] = row[i];
        }
    }                    
}
```

Comment: Your code give me a very good idea to solve the problem.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but this will strip the time when you need that done:

- First Cast the Date as type DATE, then recast it as DATETIME

  ```
  CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AS Datetime)
  ```

However, if you're just formatting it in C#, just call ToShortDateString() on the DateTime field.

**UPDATE**

So, you just need to display the time if it has a non-zero time. In that case, you could:

- Test the Hours, Minutes and Seconds to see if they are each 0.

  ```
  var date = DateTime.Now; 
  var printDate = (date.Hour == 0 && date.Minute == 0 && date.Second == 0) 
      ? date.ToShortDateString() : date.ToShortDateTimeString();
  ```

**UPDATE 2**

One other thing would be to get the time of day and then the total seconds.  This will be zero at midnight.

```
    var printDate2 = (date.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) 
        ? date.ToShortDateString() : date.ToShortDateTimeString();
```

Comment: Won't that just strip out the time stamp for everything? I think there are cases where the user wants the time.

Comment: @JacobH I would just use it on the columns that he needs to strip the time for.

Comment: I think it's me that is misunderstanding. I thought the data was stored in the same columns. If it's different, then your solution works fine.

Comment: From Oracle or SQL server, data is loaded to a DataTable, then is displayed in the webform view, so only until the data is in the DataTable I am hable to know that it is DateTime type so I can set the format.
Jacob H is right, I need Time sometimes, the problem is that I don't know which column does not have time, cause the Type for both cases is DataTime and the view display any table content.

Comment: From Oracle or SQL server, data is loaded to a DataTable, then is displayed in the web form view, only when data is in the DataTable I am able to know whether the column is DateTime type and I can set the format for presentation.
Jacob H is right, I need to show [Time] sometimes, the problem is that I don't know which column does not have time at all, cause the Type for both cases is DateTime and the view display any table content.

Comment: `.ToShortTimeString()` uses the settings the user has picked for their computer, so midnight will not be represented as "12:00 AM" in a lot of the world. (Especially if the ASP.NET thread is using the user's browser's locale setting.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good point, but once he tests to see what it produced, he can substitute that value in.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good point again.  I just added one more option, based on Total Secons of Time of Day property.

Comment: @John Pasquet, Thank you.
I was trying to avoid to loop for every row of a table to check if a value has Time and not only Date. Some of the tables we are loading might have up to 500K rows, so I was trying to avoid to look for every colum type datetime and every row of it.
I thought it may be a kind of format like there is for numbers with ##

Comment: Keep in mind also that, midnight is a valid time 00:00:00 not the absence of a time.

Comment: You can use the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function in SQL to format dates and times if that is what you are asking. `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')` result `23/05/2017`

Comment: @Jacob H, 
The selection of the fields is dynamic, so we don’t have selection specific to a certain field in certain table, it is like you `select * from <anytable>` and then show the data, otherwise your suggestion would be ok, and I would just move the format logic to the selection side.

Comment: @Kevin good point, but I would not mind to display only date (23/05/2017) for midnight  as valid time 00:00:00 .

Comment: @JosueMedrano You're not going to be displaying 500,000 records to the user in one page, so it would not take much time to sum the `.TotalMilliseconds` of the displayed rows (as in John's Update 2) to determine if the sum is zero and so the display format should be date-only.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a custom extension method to the DateTime class that returns your custom string format (this potentially saves a lot of duplicated code and provides a single place to change the format later if needed):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetCustomFormatString(this DateTime input, 
        bool excludeTimeIfZero = true)
    {
        return input.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero && excludeTimeIfZero
            ? input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            : input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
private static void Main()
{
    // DateTime.Now includes a non-zero time (except at midnight)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.GetCustomFormatString());

    // A new DateTime has a zero time value
    Console.WriteLine(new DateTime().GetCustomFormatString());

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, this is a very nice Snippet.